# In App Purchase Amount - App Store Connect API

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

My App is using in-app purchase to allow user to upgrade their account (using non-renewable subscription).

However, the price from the article itself (let say 10$) is not the actual price that will be send from Apple to my Bank account (because of the 10% commission fee).

I've been searching in the AppStore Connect API, but I don't find how to get the actual value for a single transaction ID.

Does anyone know how to get this information ?

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not provide sales data on this granular level. The App Store Connect API only supports Finance, Sales and Trends reports: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/sales_and_finance_reports

The verifyReceipt API also does not provide any monetary information (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/verifyreceipt)

None of this data provides you with transaction-level data.